# Creating elements in magento backend menu issue

Tags: xml, menu, action

I have a problem in /etc/adminhtml.xml file. This is its content:

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <attin_exportdb translate="title">
            <title>Export-DB</title>
            <sort_order>99</sort_order>
            <children>
                <export_attributes>
                    <title>Export Attributes</title>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/exportdb/index</action>
                </export_attributes>
                <export_products>
                    <title>Export Products</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <!-- <action>adminhtml/adminhello/index</action> -->
                </export_products>
                <export_categories>
                    <title>Export Categories</title>
                    <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                    <!-- <action>adminhtml/adminhello/index</action> -->
                </export_categories>
                <export_sells>
                    <title>Export Vanzari</title>
                    <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                    <!-- <action>adminhtml/adminhello/index</action> -->
                </export_sells>
            </children>
        </attin_exportdb>
    </menu>
</config>
```

and this is the controllers/AttributesController.php content:

```
  <?php
class Attin_Exportdb_AttributesController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

    public function IndexAction() {

        $this->loadLayout();  
        echo "Test";
        $this->renderLayout(); 

    }
}
```

config.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Attin_Exportdb>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Attin_Exportdb>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <exportdb>
                <class>Attin_Exportdb_Helper</class>
            </exportdb>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Attin_Exportdb</module>
                    <frontName>admin</frontName>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

So my problem is with the **action** in xml (**export/adminhtml/attributes/index**) , when i clicked on the Export Attributes it redirects me to 404? What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: show your config.xml file

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: you didnt set up a router in your config.xml file.

Comment: can you check it again please ?

Comment: I updated my post please check it again !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up a admin router first. So inside `<config>` node, you need to add this code.

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <attin_export before="Mage_Adminhtml">Attin_Export_Adminhtml</attin_export>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

This code snippet is actually tells to magento that

*"Hey Magento, I want to share your default admin frontend name. So whenever you looking for an admin url, check me too.."*

Now create a controller like this

File : `app/code/local/Attin/Export/Adminhtml/AttributeController.php`

```
<?php
class Attin_Export_Adminhtml_AttributesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

    public function IndexAction() {

        $this->loadLayout();  
        echo "Test";
        $this->renderLayout(); 

    }
}
```

Now change all action like this

```
 <action>adminhtml/attributes/index</action>
```

So let us look what happen, when we set up such url. The url can be parsed like this. `router_unique_reference/controller/method.`.

Here `adminhtml` is the `router_unique_reference`. This is defined inside the module `Mage_Adminhtml`. So Magento will now process this module and all those modules that is using the same `router_unique_reference`. Our module is now take into consideration, since we already tell to magento that we need admin fronend name through `config.xml` file.

`attributes` stands for `controller`. This will then converted to `AttributeController.php`. Now Magento checks in every module (that is previously selected in the first step) whether this controller exists. Magento will find a match in our module now. Please note we have specified in `config.xml` file in exactly where this file should search by Magento. (`Attin_Export_Adminhtml`). As per the configuration, Magento will look for this controller in `app/code/local/Attin/Export/controllers/Adminhtml/`.

`index` stands for the `method`. So magento now looks for a method `indexAction()` in `AttributeController.php`. Magento will find a match if that method exist in your config file.

Side note: All admin controller should extend from `Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action` instead of `Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action` which is used for frontend controllers.

Comment: a:5:{i:0;s:51:"Controller file was loaded but class does not exist";i:1;s:1140:"#0 /home/netlogiq/public_html/CUSTOM/attin/ef/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(326): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Controller file...')

Comment: see my detailed overview. You will get a good idea. Feel free to ask doubts if any

Answer (score 2):

Your action is wrong.
It should not contain 4 elements separated by slashed. only 3: 
`module/controller/action`.
In your case the url should look like:

`export/adminhtml_attributes/index` or `adminhtml/export/index` depending on how you set up your admin router.
If none of these 2 work, please provide the `config.xml` file of your module.

Comment: it works but what is the difference between the two of them ?

Comment: It depends how you declare the admin router for your module. You can set it up in 2 ways. One is to use the `admin` key are prefix. The other is to use your own prefix just like a frontend page. [Alan Storm describes nicely both case here](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited) See the Magento Admin URLs section. I suggest using the approach with the `admin` as the module key. It's cleaner an more consistent.

Comment: +1 for that alanstorm link. That is best source to study admin routing process. I gave him a shot in my answer too. :-)